# Template class to close HANDLES and other WINAPI's?

Tags: c++, class, templates, handle

I'm new to C++ and need some help.

I want to make a template `class`/`struct` that handles `HANDLE` and other `WINAPI`s so far  is this code:

```
template <typename type_to_open, typename returntype, returntype (WINAPI * GlobalFn)(             
type_to_open )> class Handle_Wrap {
public:
type_to_open data;
Handle_Wrap (type_to_open in_data) { data = in_data; }
~Handle_Wrap() { returntype (WINAPI * GlobalFn)( type_to_open );}
};
```

`Handle_Wrap <HANDLE, BOOL, ::FindClose> hFind ( FindFirstFileA (pattern.c_str(), &ffd) );`

I honestly don't think that its working and the compiler gives me a warning:

`warning C4101: 'GlobalFn' : unreferenced local variable`

I saw this code from the web and did some changes to it, and i don't know if this is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your destructor.  You repeat the declaration
of `GlobalFn`, rather than call it.  It should be:

```
~HandleWrap() { (*GlobalFn)( data ); }
```

Also, do you want to make this class copyable, movable or
neither?  If neither, you should take steps to prevent any of
the relevant compiler generated defaults; otherwise, you'll need
to provide the corresponding constructors (and possibly 
assignment operators).  If copyable, you'll also need some sort
of counter, *shared between all of the copies*, so that only the
last destructor frees the handle.  For movable (probably the
best solution, *if* you can be sure of having C++11), you'll
need a move constructor, which does something to ensure that the
destructor of the moved from object is a no-op.

Comment: Can you explain what copyable movable or neither means or give me some links.

Comment: They mean more or less what they say.  Copyable means that instances can be copied, and movable that they can be "moved" (a new concept in C++11).  All of the built-in types are copyable, but it is quite common for class types not to be.  (The important point here is that the compiler generated copy constructor will _not_ do what you want; it will end up with the handle being freed twice.)  Copy constructors should have been explained in whatever text you used to learn C++.

Comment: Move is more recent; basically, the compiler will only "move" an object that is about to be destructed (a temporary, for example).  When moving an object, the move constructor can take over any resources in the original object, as long as it modifies the original object in a way that ensures that it won't free the resources.  Thus, when an `std::vector` copies, it allocates new memory for the new vector, and copies all of the elements.  When it moves, the dest. object simply takes over the pointer from the source, and sets the pointers in the source to null.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the standard `unique_ptr`

```
 std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, ::FindClose> hFind = FindFirstFileA(...);
```

(Or something like that).

I suspect the problem in your code is that the compiler doesn't see your `GlobalFn` as a function call, but as a protoptype (another "win" for Most Vexing Parse) - you shouldn't need to use `WINAPI` at all, just make it a templated function pointer:

template  class Handle_Wrap
   {
     ...
     ~Handle_Wrap() { GlobalFn(data); }
   };

You'll probably also want to use add an `operator type_to_open() { return data; }`, so that you can use `FindNextFile(hFind, ...)`, rather than having to rely on `data` being public.

Comment: It's tricky, because `unique_ptr` will manage a `HANDLE*` (or a something*), which in turn means that you have to put the actual handle somewhere, _and_ dereference every time you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, I suppose in this particular case, it may not be ideal.

Comment: Which is a shame, because if he wants it movable, he'll end up having to duplicate most of the logic of `unique_ptr` in his own class.  (I've had a couple of similar cases where I wanted it shared, and ended up duplicating most of `shared_ptr`.)

Comment: I'm not sure either, but I doubt it.  And if you did, where would you put the handle?

Comment: `HANDLE` is a `void *`. So clearly if `unique_ptr<int>` stores an `int *` [somehow], a `unique_ptr<void>` would be a suitable place to keep a `void *`, aka `HANDLE` (not ALL Windows Handles are `void *`, so you may need to use other types in other cases)